# How can I use User.Identity.Name to work in a class outside of a Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

How can I use `User.Identity.Name` to work in a class outside of a Controller?
I just used like this inside class

```
private readonly static string sLogon =  HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Substring(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
```

It retruns null reference on IIS 7.5 production server even It works on development server.

Here, I've used some alternatives.

- At first I used `Environment.Username`. Which works well in development. But not after publishing. Because then `Environment.Username` yields the name of the applications pool which the app runs in. As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28VS.98%29.aspx).
- `Controller.User.Identity.Name` is used to get the desired username in controllers, works well in pre and post publishing. But it cannot be used in the context of Class .cs.
- `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` yields null reference.
- `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` works kind of same as `Environment.Username`

Do you have any ideas how to use it? Thanks

**Update**

According to environment, If I get the login id, I can get employee information such as EmployeeID, Email, etc... from Employee table. for e.g : I have one class (outside of a controller) to get Employee ID from Employee table to access like this.

`string EmployeeID = new EmployeeService().EmployeeID();`

```
private readonly static string sLogon =  HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Substring(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);

public string EmployeeID()
        {
            var employee = new Common().Employee();

            string sID = (from e in employee
                          where (e.LogonID ?? "N/A").ToLower().Contains(sLogon.ToLower())
                          select e.EmployeeID).FirstOrDefault();

            return sID;
        }
```

Comment: Can you give a rough idea of what you're trying to do? Assuming you're trying to get the username of the currently logged in user, when are you trying to use it? I.e. where are you using this "class outide of the controller"?

Comment: @RowanFreeman I just updated the question, please

Comment: When is the class being invoked? Is it before, during or after an Action is called?

Comment: Is the production server set up correctly for Windows Authentication? Is anonymous authentication disabled?

Answer (score 0):

According to the reflected code, the HttpContext.Current.User is set during the windows authentication OnAuthenticate event.

```
// System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule
private void OnAuthenticate(WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
{
    if (this._eventHandler != null)
    {
        this._eventHandler(this, e);
    }
    if (e.Context.User == null)
    {
        if (e.User != null)
        {
            e.Context.User = e.User;
            return;
        }
        if (e.Identity == WindowsAuthenticationModule.AnonymousIdentity)
        {
            e.Context.SetPrincipalNoDemand(WindowsAuthenticationModule.AnonymousPrincipal, false);
            return;
        }
        e.Context.SetPrincipalNoDemand(new WindowsPrincipal(e.Identity), false);
    }
}
```

May need to check whether on your production server, the windows authentication is enabled and anonymous authentication is disabled.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(v=WS.10).aspx